# Spring Boot "Hello World" example gives run method exception

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

Before I recieve suggestive comments questioning my intelligence I will just go out and say that I just followed the guidance provided on official Spring website (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). And as a reward I recieved an error.

Dont find it necessary to define anything that doesnt state in the documentation, Gradle build is copy-pasted, so where lies the problem?

[image]

build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Well, I see that your project has a package in it called org.springframework.boot. That is suspicious. It doesn't have a class SpringApplication in it, by any chance?

Comment: Yap, that did the trick. Thank you for your service captain